# Excel: get row labels with range and frequency

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Suppose I have a single column of whole numbers from 10 to 29. I want to create a pivot table that looks like this:

[image]

I'm having trouble getting these values, though. How can I get a range for each row label, and the frequency?

Comment: Use an assist column that says "10-12", "13-15", etc based on the number (using a nested IF), then create your pivot from that assist column

Comment: Thanks @EricF, the problem is the person I'm helping is using a Windows machine (Excel 2016) and I'm on a Mac (Excel for Mac 2011). Is there a drag-and-drop method, similar to Excel 2016, available to mac users?

Comment: Why would my method not work for Mac users? I would assume that "=IF(" is available to Mac users as well?

Comment: Hi @EricF the professor showing this in class used only clicking and drag-and-drop, and said formulae would not be necessary in this class.